# Embed multiple posts. What's the right way?

Tags: facebook

The [embed post feature](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/07/31/introducing-embedded-posts/) on facebook generates a code like this

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js#xfbml=1"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }
  (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-post"....[cut]
```

I have not found any reference on the right way to embed multiple posts on the same page.

Because this code build a `div` with a non-random id (`fb-root`) and a script tag with non-random id too.

Should I (or Can I) modify these id in order to prevent multiple elements with the same ID?

It works now for me for a coincidence?

Can I prevent the load of `all.js` script every time?

I cannot use the graph or some advanced feature, because the copy&paste should be an action made by an editor and not by a developer (I need a very simple way for include a public post on external website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the Javascript once. And the `<div class="fb-post" ...>` you add one per post that you want to embed.

Comment: and What's the purpose of fb-root?

Comment: I think the Javascript code uses it. If it doesn't you don't need to add it.